# How can I refactor a JAVA method that returns a nested MAP?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, refactoring

```
public Map<product, SortedMap<Date, ServiceInterval>> getServiceInterval(
            Contract pContract, BillCycle pBillCycle)
    {
        Map<product, SortedMap<Date, ServiceInterval>> returnMap = new HashMap<>();

        List<product> productList = getAllproducts(pContract);

        for (product product : productList)
        {
            Date billingDate = getBillingDate(product);

            createReturnMap(
                    product, returnMap,
                    billingDate, pBillCycle);
        }

        return returnMap;
    }
```

I was asked to refactor this method (simplified here) because:

*Such complex type should not be used in interfaces. 
Besides it makes the code difficult to debug.
The implementation should be hidden in the class.*

I am not sure it makes sense to refactor this.

Do you agree that is worth refactoring this method?

If yes, what approach would you use? How can one make this easier for debugging?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but I think you might want `returnMap = createReturnMap(product, billingDate, pBillCycle);`. Let the method `createReturnMap` handle creating the `Map`;

Comment: Difficult to say not seeing the entire class.

Comment: actually this code is simplified and I agree with what you said however my real task is to get rid of the Nested map in the getServiceInterval method.

Comment: How can I replace the nested map?

Comment: @bradimus Can't do that, since `createReturnMap` doesn't actually *create* the return map, but adds to it (method is badly named). If anything, you could do `returnMap.put(product, createSortedMap(product, billingDate, pBillCycle))`

Comment: You're may be looking at it the wrong way around. You need to look at how the returned value is going to be used, then you work out how to refactor you method. I suspect that just replacing the SortedMap with a new class with the appropriate methods would probably be enough to keep the reviewer happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Map<Product, SortedMap<Date, ServiceInterval>> getServiceInterval(
            Contract pContract, BillCycle pBillCycle)
```

> Such complex type should not be used in interfaces. Besides it makes
>   the code difficult to debug. The implementation should be hidden in
>   the class.

I agree. If the service is provided to another client class, it may be cumbersome to use the returned object which is a map of map. So, you could use wrapper for your maps by providing a basic way for client classes to retrieve a ServiceInterval instance matching to input parameters : so containing a `getServiceInterval()` method in the returned object  : `public ServiceInterval getServiceInterval (Product product, Date date)`

I propose product and date as input parameter as it's how you set your map of map :

```
Map<Product, SortedMap<Date, ServiceInterval>>
```

It's pseudo code written on the fly, just to show the idea:

```
public ServiceIntervalByProduct getServiceInterval(
        Contract pContract, BillCycle pBillCycle)  {
    ServiceIntervalByProduct  returnMap = new ServiceIntervalByProduct();

    List<product> productList = getAllproducts(pContract);

    for (product product : productList)
    {
        Date billingDate = getBillingDate(product);

        createReturnMap(
                product, returnMap,
                billingDate, pBillCycle);
    }

    return returnMap;
}

// First level Wrapper class
public class ServiceIntervalsByProduct{

  private Map<Product, ServiceIntervalsByDate>> mapByProduct;   

  public void add(Product product, Date date, ServiceInterval serviceInterval) {
   // add in inner map
  }

 public ServiceInterval getServiceInterval (Product product, Date date){
   // get from inner map
    return mapByProduct.get(product).getServiceInterval (date);    
 }
}


// Second level Wrapper class
public class ServiceIntervalsByDate{
  private  SortedMap<Date, ServiceInterval>> mapByDate;

  public void add(Date date, ServiceInterval serviceInterval){
   // add in inner map    
  }

  public ServiceInterval getServiceInterval (Date date){
   // get from inner map
    return mapByDate.get(date);
   }

}
```

I provide `add()` methods in the wrappers but you can gather all needed data in a constructor if you want to protect data modifications from client classes.

Comment: You are welcome. It's not very difficult to implement :)

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the nested Map with your own class, e.g. Services that offers the methods the callers need. This class will most likely use or extend a Map. The signature then becomes

```
public Map<Product, Services> getServiceInterval(Contract pContract, BillCycle pBillCycle)
```

It makes the code a little easier to read but you are spending development time and effort on it, while most likely not adding much functionality to it. Might make sense if the Services class could be extended with additional logic. Really hard to say without knowing more details.

Comment: Thanks this is a great approach, I will give it a try. I agree with you that this refactoring is a lot of effort without a great benefits though.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on provided example I don't see any reasone to have nested map at all. As I see from code you have only one billing date per product, so your nested map will have only one element for each product. To make things simpler just create one more class wich wll hold billing date and **ServiceInterval**, let's call it **BillingServiceInterval** and return **`Map<Product, BillingServiceInterval>`** from your method. Hope this helps

Comment: You are assuming that the `Date` key in the inner map is the billing date. Not knowing what `createReturnMap()` actually does, that's a big assumption.

Comment: You're right. I just try to guess because we haven't got enogh information

Comment: Then write a comment to the question requesting clarification.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't got enogh reputation points to do this

Comment: Sorry this code was simplified. I just wanted to show that the method returns a nested map and the code reviwers are asking me to get rid of it. There are several other parameters that go in this logic.

Answer (score 0):

In case for each product you get one Date and one ServiceInterval you could create a simple bean. The method would return a collection of your choice of such beans.

Comment: How do you know that there is only one `ServiceInterval` for each product? You don't know what `createReturnMap()` does.